# Xml element node is appended twice

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
 **<Content>
    <UId>1</UId>
    <FileName>Calculator.txt</FileName>
    <Image>1.jpg<Image/>
    <FullPath>1</FullPath>
    <FullPath>2</FullPath>
    <FullPath>3</FullPath>
  </Content>**
```

I want output like the above XML.  For that I have written the code below.  If fullpath is present in the existing XML document then don't add it, but using the code below the XML is incorrectly written.  Two content nodes are added.

```
string fullPath="1$2$3";
List<string> nodesToBeAdded = fullPath.Split('$').ToList();

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(filePath);

XmlNode nodeContent = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Content", null);

XmlNode nodeUID = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "UId", null);
nodeUID.InnerText = value.UId;

XmlNode nodeFileName = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "FileName", null);
nodeFileName.InnerText = value.FileName;

XmlNode nodeImage = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Image", null);
nodeImage.InnerText = value.Image;

for (int i = 0; i < nodesToBeAdded.Count - 1; i++)
{
    XmlNode nodeFullPath = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "FullPath", null);
    nodeFullPath.InnerText = nodesToBeAdded[i];

    if (xmlDocument.SelectNodes(string.Concat("//", "Content", '/', "FullPath", "[text()='" + nodesToBeAdded[i] + "']")).Count == 0)
    {
        nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeUID);
        nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeFileName);
        nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeImage);
        nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeFullPath);
    }
}//add parent node to document
xmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(nodeContent);

xmlDocument.Save(filePath);
```

Output:

```
<Content>
    <UId>1</UId>
    <FileName>Calculator.txt</FileName>
    <Image>1.jpg</Image>
    <FullPath>1</FullPath>
  </Content>
  <Content />  
  <Content />
  <Content />
  <Content />
```

Comment: Use LINQ to XML it'll be much easier.

Comment: ^^ See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693076.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your rules to write the xml, but as I could see you have to write multiple contents and the **fullpath** cant repeat in the **same content**, right?

So, as I could see the **if statement** in your code is the responsable to generate empty **<content />**  tags, because when you use the instruction

```
if (xmlDocument.SelectNodes(string.Concat("//", "Content", '/', "FullPath", "[text()='" + nodesToBeAdded[i] + "']")).Count == 0)
{
    nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeUID);
    nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeFileName);
    nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeImage);
    nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeFullPath);
}
```

you will looking for any fullpath has the **text = nodesToBeAdded[i]**, and after the first loop, your condition `if (xmlDocument.SelectNodes(string.Concat("//", "Content", '/', "FullPath", "[text()='" + nodesToBeAdded[i] + "']")).Count == 0)` will always return true and consequently the code reponsable to add all the elements on the node won't be executed.

I did some fixes in your code that allows check de current content, see below:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        string filePath = "D:\\teste.xml";
        string fullPath = "1$2$3";
        List<string> nodesToBeAdded = fullPath.Split('$').ToList();

        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDocument.Load(filePath);

        for (int item = 1; item <= 3; item++)
        {
            XmlNode nodeContent = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Content", null);

            XmlNode nodeUID = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "UId", null);
            nodeUID.InnerText = item.ToString();//value.UId;

            XmlNode nodeFileName = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "FileName", null);
            nodeFileName.InnerText = item + "-Calculator.txt";// value.FileName;

            XmlNode nodeImage = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Image", null);
            nodeImage.InnerText = item + "-Image.jpg";//value.Image;

            for (int i = 0; i < nodesToBeAdded.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlNode nodeFullPath = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "FullPath", null);
                nodeFullPath.InnerText = nodesToBeAdded[i];

                if (nodeContent.SelectNodes(string.Concat("//", "Content", '/', "FullPath", "[text()='" + nodesToBeAdded[i] + "']")).Count == 0)
                {
                    nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeUID);
                    nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeFileName);
                    nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeImage);
                    nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeFullPath);
                }
            }//add parent node to document
            xmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(nodeContent);
        }
        xmlDocument.Save("D:\\teste.xml");
    }
```

and the result

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
      <Content>
        <FullPath>1</FullPath>
        <FullPath>2</FullPath>
        <UId>1</UId>
        <FileName>1-Calculator.txt</FileName>
        <Image>1-Image.jpg</Image>
        <FullPath>3</FullPath>
      </Content>
      <Content>
        <FullPath>1</FullPath>
        <FullPath>2</FullPath>
        <UId>2</UId>
        <FileName>2-Calculator.txt</FileName>
        <Image>2-Image.jpg</Image>
        <FullPath>3</FullPath>
      </Content>
      <Content>
        <FullPath>1</FullPath>
        <FullPath>2</FullPath>
        <UId>3</UId>
        <FileName>3-Calculator.txt</FileName>
        <Image>3-Image.jpg</Image>
        <FullPath>3</FullPath>
      </Content>
    </root>"
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you XML looks like this:

```
<root>
    <Content>
        <UId>1</UId>
        <FileName>Calculator.txt</FileName>
        <Image>1.jpg</Image>
        <FullPath>1</FullPath>
        <FullPath>2</FullPath>
        <FullPath>3</FullPath>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <UId>2</UId>
        <FileName>Calculator2.txt</FileName>
        <Image>1.jpg</Image>
        <FullPath>1</FullPath>
        <FullPath>2</FullPath>
        <FullPath>3</FullPath>
    </Content>
</root>
```

You can use this http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

```
   /* 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    */
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Content")]
    public class Content {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="UId")]
        public string UId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="FileName")]
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Image")]
        public string Image { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="FullPath")]
        public List<string> FullPath { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="root")]
    public class Root {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Content")]
        public List<Content> Content { get; set; }
    }

}
```

THen you can read and generate the XML:

```
// READ
var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\file.xml");
Root root;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

using (var stream = new StringReader(data))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

// WORK ON YOUR OBJECT.
// TODO ...

// WRITE
//var root = new Root();
root.Content = new List<Content>();
root.Content.Add(new Content { UId = "1", FileName = "file1.jpg" });
root.Content.Add(new Content { UId = "2", FileName = "file2.jpg" });

//var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
serializer.Serialize(File.Create(@"C:\temp\file1.xml"), root);
```

OR

You can use this:
[image: Visual Studio -> Edit -> Paste as XML]

Wich will generate this code:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class root
{

    private rootContent[] contentField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Content")]
    public rootContent[] Content
    {
        get
        {
            return this.contentField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.contentField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class rootContent
{

    private byte uIdField;

    private string fileNameField;

    private string imageField;

    private byte[] fullPathField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte UId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fileNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fileNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Image
    {
        get
        {
            return this.imageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.imageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FullPath")]
    public byte[] FullPath
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fullPathField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fullPathField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can save it as a XML file, for example:

```
   var r = new root();
   r.Content = new rootContent[2];
   r.Content[0] = new rootContent() { UId = 1, FileName = "file1.jpg" };
   r.Content[1] = new rootContent() { UId = 2, FileName = "file2.jpg" };


   var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(root));
   serializer.Serialize(File.Create(@"C:\temp\file.xml"), r);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understood your situation, moving `xmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(nodeContent);` to an `if` block should help:

```
string fullPath="1$2$3";
List<string> nodesToBeAdded = fullPath.Split('$').ToList();

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(filePath);

XmlNode nodeContent = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Content", null);

XmlNode nodeUID = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "UId", null);
nodeUID.InnerText = value.UId;

XmlNode nodeFileName = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "FileName", null);
nodeFileName.InnerText = value.FileName;

XmlNode nodeImage = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Image", null);
nodeImage.InnerText = value.Image;

bool addNodeContent = false;
for (int i = 0; i < nodesToBeAdded.Count - 1; i++)
{
    XmlNode nodeFullPath = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "FullPath", null);
    nodeFullPath.InnerText = nodesToBeAdded[i];

    if (xmlDocument.SelectNodes(string.Concat("//", "Content", '/', "FullPath", "[text()='" + nodesToBeAdded[i] + "']")).Count == 0)
    {
        nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeUID);
        nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeFileName);
        nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeImage);
        nodeContent.AppendChild(nodeFullPath);

        addNodeContent = true;
    }
}

if (addNodeContent)
{
   //add parent node to document
   xmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(nodeContent);
}

xmlDocument.Save(filePath);
```

Otherwise, empty nodes will be added. But I'm still not sure about some moments in your code, so consider using automatic XML serialization tools provided in C#.